# output an error when someone enters a letter as a menu choice

Tags: java

I want to make this program output an error when someone enters a letter as a menu choice

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int UserIn = 0;
        double numberInputA;
        double numberInputB;
        double Answer;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (UserIn != 5) {
            System.out.println("What type of calculation would you like to perform?");
            System.out.println("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n" +
                               "3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Exit");
            UserIn = input.nextInt();

            if (UserIn > 5) {
                System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            } else if (UserIn < 1) {
                System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            }

            if (UserIn < 5) {
                System.out.println("Enter first number:");
                numberInputA = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second number");
                numberInputB = input.nextDouble();

                if (UserIn == 1) {
                    Answer = numberInputA + numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1 is:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2 is:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is : " + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 2) {
                    Answer = numberInputA - numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 3) {
                    Answer = numberInputA * numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 4) {
                    Answer = numberInputA / numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

            if (UserIn == 5) {
                System.out.println("Program exited");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, we don't do the "please do X for me" thing. Just know that you can use (for example) RegEx to check if a string contains a valid number and you can use the `Integer.parseInt(String)`-method to get an `int` from your `String`.

Comment: Most of the code for handling each choice is exactly the same; I'd consider tweaking things a bit to make it easier to read and modify. Also note that, say, -10 is < 5, but is not a valid menu choice. Please, please indent your code consistently--it helps readability considerably.

Answer (score 1):

If you´d like to have a loop function until the user makes a correct input you could use this snippet.

```
while(true){
   try{
      UserIn = input.nextInt();
      break;
   }catch (Exception ex){
         System.out.println("Not an acceptable input.");
         input.nextLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check wether a character is a letter or not using 'Character.isLetter(char)'

```
if(Character.isLetter(UserIn))
{
    //do something
}
```

Hope this helps!

(PS: please format your text a little clearer in the future, and be clear in what your question exactly is, not only in the title bar but also in the main content of the question.)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply apply try catch block in your code to output an error at your convenience like:

```
    try{
        while (UserIn != 5) {
            System.out.println("What type of calculation would you like to perform?");
            System.out.println("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n" +
                    "3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Exit");
            UserIn = input.nextInt();

            if (UserIn > 5) {
                System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            } else if (UserIn < 1) {
                System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            }

            if (UserIn < 5) {
                System.out.println("Enter first number:");
                numberInputA = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second number");
                numberInputB = input.nextDouble();

                if (UserIn == 1) {
                    Answer = numberInputA + numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1 is:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2 is:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is : " + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 2) {
                    Answer = numberInputA - numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 3) {
                    Answer = numberInputA * numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }

                if (UserIn == 4) {
                    Answer = numberInputA / numberInputB;
                    System.out.println("Number 1:" + numberInputA);
                    System.out.println("Number 2:" + numberInputB);
                    System.out.println("Result is :" + Answer);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

            if (UserIn == 5) {
                System.out.println("Program exited");
            }

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input !!! Program will exit");
    }
```